# How to produce a matrix with all possible permutations of n sets of 5 values (with duplicates) in C/C++

Tags: c++, cartesian-product

I am essentially trying to, in c++, produce a matrix (dimensions (5^n)x(n)) where each row is a possible permutation of these 5 values: -2,-1,0,1,2. For example, if I wanted to get the matrix for 3 sets of these values, it would look like:

125 x 3

-2 -2 -2

-2 -2 -1

-2 -2 0

.  .  .

.  .  .

.  .  .

2  2  0

2  2  1

2  2  2

and the matrix for 4 sets would look like:

625 x 4

-2 -2 -2 -2

-2 -2 -2 -1

-2 -2 -2 0

.  .  .  .

.  .  .  .

.  .  .  .

2  2  2  0

2  2  2  1

2  2  2  2

In other words, I am trying to implement MATLAB's "permn" function in C++. I am sure this is doable with a recursive function somehow (with vector of integer vectors to represent the matrix), but tracking the correct value to place in the correct index is tough to wrap my head around. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is the Cartesian product that you want.

Comment: So, what's stopping you from writing it?  Search the internet for "c++ faq matrix", also `std::vector`.

Comment: `(5^n)x(n)` should give you a hint as to what you're trying to do: you're counting in base `5`.

Answer (score 1):

A hard code solution would be:

```
for (int a1 : {-2,-1,0,1,2}) {
  for (int a2 : {-2,-1,0,1,2}) {
    for (int a3 : {-2,-1,0,1,2}) {
      for (int a4 : {-2,-1,0,1,2}) {
        for (int a5 : {-2,-1,0,1,2}) {
            do_job5(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may use the following for a more generic way:

```
bool increase(std::size_t size, std::vector<std::size_t>& it)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = it.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        const std::size_t index = size - 1 - i;
        ++it[index];
        if (it[index] > size) {
            it[index] = 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename F, typename T>
void self_cartesian_product(F&& f, const std::vector<T>& v, std::size_t N)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> it(N, 0);

    do {
        f(v, it);
    } while (increase(v.size(), it));
}
```

With call similar to

```
self_cartesian_product([](const auto& v, const auto& indexes)
     {
         for (auto i : indexes) {
             std::cout << v[i] << " ";
         }
         std::cout << std::endl;
     },
     std::vector<int>{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2},
     3);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Xs7n6s)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to implement this (it is a component of something I am using for some GPS software) and report back later.